# quickbooks: script to backup ALL online data to local database server

Tags: quickbooks-online

I wanted to write a script which gets me a snapshot of all journal entries in quickbooks online to a local db server. This data from local db is required to show data in an analytical dashboard of my site.

As I was going through quickbooks API, I found journal entry api which fetches all the journal related info specific to journalID:-
https://developer.intuit.com/v2/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#?id=JournalEntry

What I require is an api which gets ALL the journal entries which exist up to date.

Please share any leads or pointers for above requirement.

Tks